# Can I automatically replace characters in my urls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, replace, routes

I have the following route: `get '/pages/:name', to: "pages#show", as: 'page'` for my model `Page`. Can I automatically replace a certain character with another?

Specifically, if a Page has a `:name` containing the character "/", can I automatically replace that character with "_" or something else in the final url?

Comment: Why in the `route.rb`.. you can change it from the source right ?

Comment: If name has a / character, then it won't hit that route, unless you are encoding the slash as '%2F'

Comment: @ArupRakshit I guess I could, but it would be more efficient to change it in routes.rb, rather than change every single link on my app.

Comment: @tlehman Wait, are you saying that if I encode the slash as "%2F", then there's no need to change my route?

Comment: @JoeMorano Yup, should I post that as an answer?

Comment: @tlehman How exactly would that work though? If I put a `%2F` in the name, like "Superman%2FClark Kent", it just prints exactly like that, instead of insterting a slash.

Comment: @JoeMorano You would want to use `URI.decode("Superman%2FClark Kent")`, that will convert it back to `"Superman/Clark Kent"`

Comment: @tlehman So I'd have to use that every time I want to print out `Page.name`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81685/discussion-between-tlehman-and-joe-morano).

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
get '/pages/:name', to: "pages#show", as: 'page'
```

with

```
get '/:name', to: redirect {|path_params, _| "/pages/#{path_params[:name].gsub('/','_')}" }, as: 'page'
get '/pages/:name' => 'pages#show'
```

Comment: Now I get this error: `URI::InvalidURIError` /
`bad URI(is not URI?): /pages/[name]`

Comment: How are you trying to access this path? Are you using page_path(name: "____")?